# Drupal: Views, can the displays have different styles for the view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've created several displays for my View.

I thought that I could assign different styles (Gallery, Table, etc) of the view for each display but I realized that only 1 Style is used for all Displays.

The reason I wanted to change is because I'm using DraggableViews, and I would like to keep the same order for all displays, when the user drag some items on the display with draggable nodes.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

They can.

See http://drupal.org/node/352970

The idea is to use specific names for template files, also called template-suggestions. 
Some examples are:

> The files `views-view--alpha--page.tpl.php` and
>   `views-view--alpha--block.tpl.php`, for instance, would control those
>   two types of displays for the alpha view.
>
> The file `views-view--page.tpl.php` would control all views with a "page"
>   display.
>
> The file `views-view--page-1.tpl.php` would control the display
>   on the first page of all views (for those that use a pager), while
>   `views-view--alpha--page-1.tpl.php` would override that display for the
>   alpha view.

If you want more template suggestions, check out the Theme Developer. that resembles somewhat the Firebug, but allows searching for all kinds of template suggestions and theme-function naming documentation; you click on an item in your page and it shows you what names and files to use to override.

http://drupal.org/node/209561

You mentioned a list (unformatted) and a table. You will theme that, using the following files:

- `views-view--list.tpl.php` (overrides all lists by any view)
- `views-view--table.tpl.php`  (overrides all tables by any view)
- `views-view--YourViewName-table.tpl.php` overrides the table view for that view.

Comment: hi thanks for links. It is still not clear how to select an "unformatted list" or a "table" style from a template. What I want is to assign different styles to different Views (from drupal back-end this is not possible because they all change).

Comment: A second question. The theme developer you suggested looks really cool, but it is not ready to download it (red version), are you using it anyway ?

Comment: Yes, I use it anyway. You should not use -dev versions on a production environment, but you won't run development tools on a production environment anyway.
It is a great tool to use locallly while developing.

Comment: And about your problem with the ever changing views-styles: sure, that is what views do. 
That, is the biggest problem with views in the first place: allows you to change stuff online, but as soon as your theme depends on it, you loose that ability entirely.

Comment: Just to clarify: it is possible to have more than 1 view template for the same type of display if you have 2 different displays in the same view. 
views-view--admin-content--page.tpl.php
views-view--admin-content--page-1.tpl.php

Comment: hi, so the last comment is not clear to me. Can I select the preferred style option (table, gallery, not formatted, etc) for EACH display, from the custom php templates ? (I know I can customize the code for each display, but what I precisely need is to change the parameter specifying the Style) thanks