# How to create a View with multiple displays with different formats (e.g. HTML List, Draggable Table) in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

I am trying to create a View with two page displays, one that uses HTML List and another that uses Draggable Table, per the instructions for using the DraggableViews module (http://drupal.org/node/283498). However, whenever I change the format for one of the displays, it also changes for the other. Is it possible? The DraggableViews documentation (and Issues for DraggableViews) imply that it is.

Also, I know that an almost identical question was asked last year for Drupal 6 [Drupal: Views, can the displays have different styles for the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159895/drupal-views-can-the-displays-have-different-styles-for-the-view) , but no satisfactory answer was given.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have 2 displays. Do this:
1. For the first Display, click on Format.
2. In the Top : 'For' -> choose 'This page' ('This x' where x is what you display)
3. For the second Display do the same.

Basically, for all items in a view, you can choose if it applies for all display or for the current one.
Hope it is clear